# ansible sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Tags: ansible, sudo, aws-cloudformation

I need to run playbooks on Vagrant boxes and on aws when I setup environment with cloud formation.

In Vagrant file I use ansible-local and everything works fine

```
name: Setup Unified Catalog Webserver  
    hosts: 127.0.0.1  
    connection: local  
  become: yes  
  become_user: root
  roles: generic
```

However when I create instance in AWS the ansible playbook fails with error:
`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`
This happen because it is run as root and it doesnt have tty. But I dont know how to fix it without making change in `/etc/sudoers` to allow `!requiretty`

Is there any flags I can setup in ansible.cfg or in my Cloud Formation template?

```
  "#!/bin/bash\n", "\n", "   
 echo 'Installing Git'\n","  
  yum --nogpgcheck -y install git ansible htop nano wget\n",
 "wget https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/XXX -O /root/.ssh/id_rsa\n", 
"chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa\n", 
"ssh-keyscan 172.31.7.235 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts\n",
 "git clone git@172.31.7.235:something/repo.git /root/repo\n", 
"ansible-playbook /root/env/ansible/test.yml\n
```

Comment: Why does it need to be ran as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the following solutions for myself:
 1. Change requiretty in `/etc/sudoers` with `sed` run playbooks and change it back.

```
 "#!/bin/bash\n", "\n", "  
 echo 'Installing Git'\n"," 
 yum --nogpgcheck -y install git ansible htop nano wget\n",  
 "wget https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xx/ansible -O /root/.ssh/id_rsa\n",  
 "chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa\n",   
  "ssh-keyscan 172.31.9.231 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts\n",   
  "git clone git@172.31.5.254:somerepo/dev.git /root/dev\n",   
  "sed -i 's/Defaults    requiretty/Defaults    !requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers\n", 
  "\n", 
  "ansible-playbook /root/dev/env/ansible/uk.yml\n",   
  "\n",   
  "sed -i 's/Defaults    !requiretty/Defaults    requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers\n"
```

OR
2.  In ansible playbook specify variable:

```
 - name: Setup 
 hosts: 127.0.0.1
 connection: local
 sudo: {{ require_sudo }}
 roles:
    - generic
```

Run in AWS Cloud Formation template would be

```
   "ansible-playbook -e require_sudo=False /root/dev/env/ansible/uk.yml\n"
```

And for Vagrant in ansible.cfg it can be specified

```
  require_sudo=True
```

3. Also in CF template may identify who is running and the pass variable

   `ansible-playbook -e$(id -u |egrep '^0$' > /dev/null && require_sudo=False || require_sudo=True; echo "require_sudo=$require_sudo") /apps/ansible/uk.yml`

Comment: `sudo` is deprecated in ansible, `become` and `become_user` are supported to be used.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix this by setting the `transport = paramiko` configuration in `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: Great solution. This worked for me too and is much less intrusive than the accepted answer.

Comment: On my side I needed to change my env variable with `export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/path/to/file.cfg` as it wasn't taken into account even without my env variable being set and config file present in the working dir with the playbook. My own issue on the side, this answer works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specific connection: paramiko within just one playbook versus a global configuration in ansible.cfg, you can add `connection: paramiko` following in the playbook, example:

```
- name: Run checks after deployments
  hosts: all
  # https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1369
  connection: paramiko
  gather_facts: True
```